# Unix Time-Stamps in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unix-timestamp

Is anyone else experiencing problems with Graph API requests that use UNIX time stamps this morning? For example, last night the following query worked, but it does not work this morning- perhaps it has something to do with the recent server issues reported by Facebook last night?

Query entered into Facebook Graph API Explorer:

`/[pageid]/posts&since=1311062400&until=1313740800?fields=id&limit=10000`

Error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unknown path components: /posts&since=1311062400&until=1313740800",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2500
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is incorrect

```
/posts&since=1311062400&until=1313740800
      ^
      |
-------
```

That should be `?`

`/posts?since=1311062400&until=1313740800`

Comment: Thank you- sorry for asking a stupid question! Did this change recently? The & operator worked as recently as yesterday if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @ChrisBail Query strings normally start with a character denoting the query... which is `?`